# Full-time to Part-time consequences

Tags: quitting, work-time, student, fulltime, part-time

I am in a conundrum at the moment.

I graduated last year June, and then got a job working as a Support consultant. After 8 months I got bored and left to another company as a Support tech as well. Both companies are in the same web hosting business.

So, I resumed my new job in February and currently done with probation. However, I am now hoping to do a Masters and looking at asking my employer to let me switch to part time. Our shifts are 24/7 shifts so I'm hoping they can find a slot for me.

Now I don't know how to go about telling my boss, and not sure when I should tell him. The course starts in September and I do not want a situation where they say no and dismiss me if I tell them now.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is too localized.

Comment: Too localized is no longer a reason to close a question...

Comment: Hey Booboo, and welcome to [workplace.se]! Could you please explain your problem and desired solution a bit more clearly? Right now I'm confused at what the problem is with just asking your boss to switch you to part time. Do you have a specific reason you're worried about just asking/telling him? A clarifying [edit] may help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Talk to him around the first of June, and tell him what you would like to do, and ask him if he can make it work.

Good help, especially help that's already been trained, is hard to come by, and allowances are generally made.

If you're willing to cover holidays and weekends (when school's out) so that the full-timers can have more of those off, you'll probably get a lot of cooperation.

Comment: +1 Most places LOVE a part timer who is willing to work extra during holidays.

Comment: @Booboo, I second WesleyLong. The sooner you talk to your management, the easier it is for them to make accommodations for you. I've done plenty of studying after hours while I was on call, backing up the monitoring engineer. The only time you really need to be concerned about not being interrupted is when you are doing an exam - that's  about three or four times per course in one semester. There is a huge difference in commitment between doing your MS on a part-time basis and doing it on a full-time basis, by the way. Please clarify for us whether you're doing your MS on a F/T or P/T basis.

Answer (score 0):

a lot of us have been in that situation before. Going full time to school does not necessarily mean that you have to lower your workload.

Many have and are completing their Masters programs while joggling family and work and making it happen.

At one point or another you will be meeting with your manager to talk about your goals. Part of that conversation will be around self-development. Many companies "pay" their employees’ masters degrees when it's business related, many other companies provide college tuition reimbursement for non-related degrees.

These benefits are usually available to employees after they have been with the company for a year.

Here is a link to a decent article on the matter.
http://www.petersons.com/graduate-schools/guide-students-graduate-school.aspx

Depending on what field you are in, it could be advantageous to remain working while pursuing your masters.  If part time is what you really want to do, then make sure you research your company to see if they even offer such option in your department.

Good Luck!